# Gulpfile.coffee not working

Tags: coffeescript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I started a project a couple of weeks ago and my gulpfile was working just fine. I have some time today so I thought I would continue working on my project, however I've noticed that all of my gulp files are not working. I'm not getting any errors and I looked over my file it appears to be fine. But, when I try to compile no css file is created. Below is my code. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
gulp = require('gulp')
jshint = require('gulp-jshint')
sass = require('gulp-sass')
concat = require('gulp-concat')
uglify = require('gulp-uglify')
rename = require('gulp-rename')

gulp.task 'lint', ->
  gulp.src('js/*.js')
  .pipe(jshint())
  .pipe jshint.reporter('default')

gulp.task 'sass', ->
  gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe gulp.dest('dist/css')

gulp.task 'scripts', ->
  gulp.src('js/*.js')
  .pipe(concat('all.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
  .pipe(rename('all.min.js'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe gulp.dest('dist')

gulp.task 'watch', ->
  gulp.watch 'js/*.js', [
  'lint'
  'scripts'
]
gulp.watch 'scss/*.scss', [ 'sass' ]
  return

gulp.task 'default', [
  'lint'
  'sass'
  'scripts'
]
```

This is my folder structure:
[image]

When I compile I get no errors, but no CSS folder or file is created.

Answer (score 0):

Wow simple path issue ... my gulp.src was wrong.

```
gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
```

should be ...

```
gulp.src('sass/*.scss')
```